Truffle Test Error: UnhandledRejections detected VM Exception while processing transaction: revert code: -32000
I am still learning solidity and using Ganache.
Below is the contract I am trying to execute:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract FundMe {

  address payable public donee;
  mapping(address => uint256) public donations;

  constructor() {
    donee = payable(msg.sender);
  }

  error AlreadyDonated();

  function donate(address donor, uint256 amount) external payable {
    if (donations[donor] > 0) revert AlreadyDonated();
    donations[donor] += amount;
    donee.transfer(amount);
  }
}

1_deploy.js
const FundMe = artifacts.require('FundMe');
module.exports = function (deployer) {
deployer.deploy(FundMe, {from: '0x0d883aD63096c49D5a0BD47155A429E7BCaD83CD'})
}

test.js:
const FundMe = artifacts.require("FundMe")

contract('FundMe', (accounts) => {
    it('donating 10 eth from A', async () => {
        const instance = await FundMe.deployed();
        instance.donate('0xB7D420596F48233735e20E311E81d24954a2aDAb', 1000000000000000000n)
    });
    it('donating 70 eth from B', async () => {
        const instance = await FundMe.deployed();
        instance.donate('0x9b82f656556298E5c4bfacA43Bb412564C0a3F3c', 7000000000000000000n)
    })
});


Error I get when truffle test:
1) Contract: FundMe
       "after each" hook: after test in "Contract: FundMe":
     done() called multiple times in hook <Contract: FundMe "after each" hook: after test in "Contract: FundMe"> ... in addition, done() received error: Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert

UnhandledRejections detected
Promise {
  <rejected> Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
      at Context.<anonymous> (/Users/username/Task/smart-contract/test/test.js:8:18)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
    code: -32000,
    data: {
      hash: null,
      programCounter: 437,
      result: '0x',
      reason: null,
      message: 'revert'
    },
    reason: undefined,
    hijackedStack: 'Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert\n' +
      '    at /Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/provider/wrapper.js:25:1\n' +
      '    at /Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/provider/wrapper.js:166:1\n' +
      '    at /Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js:127:1\n' +
      '    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)',
    uncaught: true
  }

Any suggestions would be helpful.

I recommend you to switch to Foundry or Hardhat since Truffle is outdated and barely used nowadays.

The donate() function in your FundMe contract is marked as payable, meaning it expects to receive ether along with the function call. However, in your test cases, you're not sending any ether when you call the function. This can be the reason for the transaction revert.
You should send ether along with the transaction when calling the donate function. So, your revised test.js would be:
const FundMe = artifacts.require("FundMe")

contract('FundMe', (accounts) => {
    it('donating 10 eth from A', async () => {
        const instance = await FundMe.deployed();
        instance.donate('0xB7D420596F48233735e20E311E81d24954a2aDAb', 1000000000000000000n, { value: 1000000000000000000n })
    });
    it('donating 70 eth from B', async () => {
        const instance = await FundMe.deployed();
        instance.donate('0x9b82f656556298E5c4bfacA43Bb412564C0a3F3c', 7000000000000000000n, { value: 7000000000000000000n })
    })
});

